# Spring Cloud Dataflow on Bluemix - Ticktock example error

Tags: spring, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-dataflow

I was experimenting with Spring Cloud Data Flow (version 1.0.0.M2) on Cloud Foundry. Specifically I'm using, Bluemix for my task.

I used those references to sucessfully build a Cloud Foundry server:
https://github.com/lshannon/spring-cloud-data-flow-demo

http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-admin-cloudfoundry/docs/1.0.0.M2/reference/html/getting-started.html

I started the server, connected the local shell, successfully registered the default processors, sinks and sources.

The environment variables used are `($1,$2,$3,$4)` are my personal data:

```
cf set-env $APP_NAME SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_API_ENDPOINT https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net 
cf set-env $APP_NAME SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ORGANIZATION $1
cf set-env $APP_NAME SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_SPACE $2
cf set-env $APP_NAME SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_DOMAIN eu-gb.mybluemix.net
cf set-env $APP_NAME SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_SERVICES redis01,rabbit
cf set-env $APP_NAME SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_USERNAME $3
cf set-env $APP_NAME SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_PASSWORD $4
cf set-env $APP_NAME SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_SKIP_SSL_VALIDATION false
```

I double checked those variables in the Bluemix instance and everything is correct.

Then I tried to recreate the basic stream example using the shell, which is:

```
stream create luketicktock --definition "time | log" --deploy
```

The shell output is:

```
Created and deployed new stream 'luketicktock'
```

However, I cannot see any deployed Cloud Foundry apps able to reproduce such a stream.

```
   2016-07-02T18:27:34.74+0200 [RTR/0]      OUT approver-dataflow-v2.eu-gb.mybluemix.net - [02/07/2016:16:27:34 +0000] "GET /streams/definitions?page=0&size=10 HTTP/1.1" 200 0 387 "http://approver-dataflow-v2.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/admin-ui/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" 159.122.215.10:39562 x_forwarded_for:"87.14.219.53" x_forwarded_proto:"http" vcap_request_id:781a16d0-9b21-4549-4403-3b95744b936a response_time:0.046310147 app_id:59f2c573-1b54-4480-81e3-6a064260820a x_global_transaction_id:"1105927831"
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT 2016-07-02 16:27:39.143 ERROR 29 --- [io-61588-exec-5] o.s.c.d.s.c.CloudFoundryAppDeployer      : Error creating app luketicktock-log
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.OAuth2AccessDeniedException: Error requesting access token.
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.retrieveToken(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:145) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.password.ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken(ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider.java:47) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:221) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:173) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.createRequest(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:592) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.doExecute(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:128) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:572) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:280) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.cloudfoundry.spring.util.AbstractSpringOperations.lambda$get$3(AbstractSpringOperations.java:85) ~[cloudfoundry-client-spring-2.0.0.M4.jar!/:2.0.0.M4]
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.cloudfoundry.spring.util.AbstractSpringOperations.lambda$null$1(AbstractSpringOperations.java:66) ~[cloudfoundry-client-spring-2.0.0.M4.jar!/:2.0.0.M4]
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxYieldingEmitter$YieldingSignalEmitter.request(FluxYieldingEmitter.java:75) ~[reactor-core-2.5.0.M3.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at reactor.core.util.DeferredSubscription.set(DeferredSubscription.java:71) ~[reactor-core-2.5.0.M3.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnPipeline.onSubscribe(FluxSubscribeOn.java:129) ~[reactor-core-2.5.0.M3.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at reactor.core.subscriber.SignalEmitter.start(SignalEmitter.java:170) ~[reactor-core-2.5.0.M3.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxYieldingEmitter.subscribe(FluxYieldingEmitter.java:43) ~[reactor-core-2.5.0.M3.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:153) ~[reactor-core-2.5.0.M3.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.subscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:170) ~[reactor-core-2.5.0.M3.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOn$SourceSubscribeTask.run(FluxSubscribeOn.java:363) ~[reactor-core-2.5.0.M3.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at reactor.core.publisher.Computations$ProcessorWorker.onNext(Computations.java:919) ~[reactor-core-2.5.0.M3.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at reactor.core.publisher.Computations$ProcessorWorker.onNext(Computations.java:883) ~[reactor-core-2.5.0.M3.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at reactor.core.publisher.WorkQueueProcessor$QueueSubscriberLoop.run(WorkQueueProcessor.java:842) ~[reactor-core-2.5.0.M3.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport$AccessTokenErrorHandler.handleError(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:244) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:641) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:597) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:565) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.retrieveToken(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:137) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:39.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT    ... 24 common frames omitted
2016-07-02T18:27:40.70+0200 [RTR/2]      OUT approver-dataflow-v2.eu-gb.mybluemix.net - [02/07/2016:16:27:40 +0000] "GET /streams/definitions?page=0&size=10 HTTP/1.1" 200 0 384 "http://approver-dataflow-v2.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/admin-ui/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" 159.122.215.11:30146 x_forwarded_for:"87.14.219.53" x_forwarded_proto:"http" vcap_request_id:ecaaca33-cc82-4c4e-4cd8-c81a431c4f4f response_time:0.009798874 app_id:59f2c573-1b54-4480-81e3-6a064260820a x_global_transaction_id:"3460948721"
2016-07-02T18:27:43.51+0200 [App/0]      OUT 2016-07-02 16:27:43.519 ERROR 29 --- [io-61588-exec-5] o.s.c.d.s.c.CloudFoundryAppDeployer      : Error creating app luketicktock-time
2016-07-02T18:27:43.51+0200 [App/0]      OUT org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.OAuth2AccessDeniedException: Error requesting access token.
2016-07-02T18:27:43.51+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.retrieveToken(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:145) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:43.51+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.password.ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken(ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider.java:47) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:43.51+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:221) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:43.51+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:173) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:43.51+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.createRequest(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:43.51+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:592) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
2016-07-02T18:27:43.51+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.doExecute(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:128) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:43.52+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:572) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
2016-07-02T18:27:43.52+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:280) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
2016-07-02T18:27:43.52+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.cloudfoundry.spring.util.AbstractSpringOperations.lambda$get$3(AbstractSpringOperations.java:85) ~[cloudfoundry-client-spring-2.0.0.M4.jar!/:2.0.0.M4]
2016-07-02T18:27:43.52+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.cloudfoundry.spring.util.AbstractSpringOperations.lambda$null$1(AbstractSpringOperations.java:66) ~[cloudfoundry-client-spring-2.0.0.M4.jar!/:2.0.0.M4]
2016-07-02T18:27:43.52+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxYieldingEmitter$YieldingSignalEmitter.request(FluxYieldingEmitter.java:75) ~[reactor-core-2.5.0.M3.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:43.52+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at reactor.core.util.DeferredSubscription.set(DeferredSubscription.java:71) ~[reactor-core-2.5.0.M3.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:43.52+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnPipeline.onSubscribe(FluxSubscribeOn.java:129) ~[reactor-core-2.5.0.M3.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:43.52+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at reactor.core.subscriber.SignalEmitter.start(SignalEmitter.java:170) ~[reactor-core-2.5.0.M3.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:43.52+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxYieldingEmitter.subscribe(FluxYieldingEmitter.java:43) ~[reactor-core-2.5.0.M3.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:43.52+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:153) ~[reactor-core-2.5.0.M3.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:43.52+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.subscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:170) ~[reactor-core-2.5.0.M3.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:43.52+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOn$SourceSubscribeTask.run(FluxSubscribeOn.java:363) ~[reactor-core-2.5.0.M3.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:43.52+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at reactor.core.publisher.Computations$ProcessorWorker.onNext(Computations.java:919) ~[reactor-core-2.5.0.M3.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:43.52+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at reactor.core.publisher.Computations$ProcessorWorker.onNext(Computations.java:883) ~[reactor-core-2.5.0.M3.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:43.52+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at reactor.core.publisher.WorkQueueProcessor$QueueSubscriberLoop.run(WorkQueueProcessor.java:842) ~[reactor-core-2.5.0.M3.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:43.52+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
2016-07-02T18:27:43.52+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
2016-07-02T18:27:43.52+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
2016-07-02T18:27:43.52+0200 [App/0]      OUT Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized
2016-07-02T18:27:43.52+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
2016-07-02T18:27:43.52+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport$AccessTokenErrorHandler.handleError(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:244) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:43.52+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:641) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
2016-07-02T18:27:43.52+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:597) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
2016-07-02T18:27:43.52+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:565) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
2016-07-02T18:27:43.52+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.retrieveToken(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:137) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-07-02T18:27:43.52+0200 [App/0]      OUT    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

It seems that the dataflow server fails in requesting the access token to Bluemix to creating the stream. Did I make something wrong?

Thanks for your support!

Comment: I just tried with server version 1.0.0.M3 on Bluemix and I got the same error. Just to be sure I tried with a trial account on Pivotal PAAS and everything works perfectly. So it seems a problem related to the Bluemix implementation of Cloud Foundry...maybe it's related to https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client/issues/513

Answer (score 0):

This is usually observed when deploying to Cloud Foundry without valid self-signed certificate. If this is on your development environment, you can skip the SSL validation by the following.

`cf set-env $APP_NAME SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_SKIP_SSL_VALIDATION true`

As of today, [Spring Cloud Data Flow](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/) "core" is at RC1 and the Cloud Foundry [implementation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/) is at M3. As listed in the [RC1 blog](https://spring.io/blog/2016/06/21/spring-cloud-data-flow-1-0-rc1-released), there were several new improvements along with terminology changes, so upgrading to the latest release is highly recommended.

Comment: Unfotunately I've also tried this approach without success. The fact is that the only version that works is the 1.0.0.M1 because it exposes: `SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN_URI` and `SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_USER_AUTHORIZATION_URI` that in case of Bluemix are respectively: `https://login.eu-gb.bluemix.net/UAALoginServerWAR/oauth/token` and `https://login.eu-gb.bluemix.net/UAALoginServerWAR/oauth/authorize`. Unfortunately, later versions does not allow that.  See [ref](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-cloud-dataflow/1.0.0.M1/reference/htmlsingle/#_deploying_on_cloud_foundry)

Comment: Please refer to the comment in [#772](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/772)

Comment: Unluckily, I was not able to solve the problem using your comments. I suspect that the problem is related to the underlying cf-client-java used by the DataFlow server that fails in the login procedure with the Bluemix environment as mentioned [here](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client/issues/513).

Comment: Just tried with a nightly build of 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT still without success. The part on data-server.yml refers to securing your dataflow instance with oauth not connecting to the Bluemix management. So I'm now clueless :(

Comment: As you'd already know, the `cf-java-client` team is already investigating this via [cloudfoundry/cf-java-client/issues#513](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client/issues/513#issuecomment-230718742) - once this is resolved, you can then retry the stream deployment.